# partitioning of vertices of graph G and tree packing theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I need an explanation and  an example of a graph for which this theorem(tree packing theorem), holds true .I tried to understand it but couldn't reach anywhere .

Tree packing theorem

A graph G contains k pairwise edge-disjoint spanning trees if and
only if for every partition P of V (G), the graph G/P has at least k(|P|-1) edges.

Comment: When you draw a complete graph on $4$ vertices, i.e., $K_4$, and consider edge-disjoint spanning trees: what do you find? What do you see if you play with this simple example?